# Firebase. getDocs returns an empty array and an infinite loop occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I want to create a document search string from firebase. When I enter values that are not in the Firebase collection, getDocs always returns an empty array and an infinite loop occurs.

The place where the endless cycle happens:

```
  export async function get() {
    const query = query(collectionRef, orderBy("title"), startAt("Abbb"), endAt("Abbb\uf8ff"));
    const snapshot = await getDocs(query);
  }
```

I don't understand why there is an infinite loop. I just want my snapshot to be empty so nothing is displayed

Here is my collection:

```
const collectionRef = getCollectionRef<Model>("collectionName") // CollectionReference<Model>
```

```
  /**
   * Getting typed collectionReference.
   * @param collectionName - Collection name.
   */
  function getCollectionRef<T = DocumentData>(collectionName):CollectionReference<T> {
    return collection(database, collectionName) as CollectionReference<T>;
  }
```

I realized that the problem occurs in this line. It is after it that the function starts executing again.

```
    const snapshot = await getDocs(query);
```

Comment: The small individual snippets do not help in finding the issue. Can you please share the complete code of the component as a single block of code? We cannot even see where `get()` function is being called from.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have changed my code to be more abstract to make it more understandable for you. And then I realized the problem, it was the wrong dependencies in useEffect!

Comment: Your code could be failing for a number of reasons and you'll never know why because there's no error handling. I would suggest implementing some error handling in your code - that can be very revealing and help narrow down where and why errors are occurring. I would also suggest reviewing the documentation on [Get Documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) as there is some example code there.